# Code doesn't put a text into a textbox as expected without any errors

Tags: c#, winforms

I am writing a code for a simple Windows Forms application that should calculate with two numbers in two different textboxes and then it should put the result into the third textbox. There are three different buttons one for multiplication (without error checking), one for multiplication (with error checking) and one for division (also with error checking.

My IDE doesn't return any errors and the warnings that are present don't seem to relate to the issue anyhow. The problem is quite simple really when I put in the two numbers the final result won't get printed into the third textbox as expected and I just can't figure out why. I think it is some simple issue that I don't understand yet as I'm a total beginner.

This is my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RuntimeErrors
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int userInputNumber;
            int multiplier;
            int result;
            userInputNumber = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            multiplier = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
            result = userInputNumber * multiplier;
            textBox3.Text = result.ToString();
        }

        protected void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int userInputNumber;
            int multiplier;
            int result;
            try
            {
                userInputNumber = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
                multiplier = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
                result = userInputNumber * multiplier;
                textBox3.Text = result.ToString();
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Using non-integer variables is not allowed. Please use an integer.", "Input Error",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            catch (OverflowException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Calculation overloaded. Please use a number in range.", "Overflow Error",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unknown system error code: 10", "Unknown System Error",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        protected void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int userInputNumber;
            int divider;
            int result;
            try
            {
                userInputNumber = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
                divider = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
                result = userInputNumber / divider;
                textBox3.Text = result.ToString();
            }
            catch (DivideByZeroException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Dividing by zero is not allowed. Please pick a different number.", "Division Error",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Using non-integer variables is not allowed. Please use an integer.", "Input Error",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            catch (OverflowException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Calculation overloaded. Please use a number in range.", "Overflow Error",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unknown system error code: 10", "Unknown System Error",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check on the designer that indeed the button clicks are registered.

Comment: Why do you have, e.g., `protected void button1_Click(...)`? When an event handler is added in the designer, it's usually generated as `private void`. Did you add these handlers *manually*? Did you *wire* the handler to the Controls' events (is the event actually subscribed to)?

Comment: Do you know how to set breakpoints? Check if event handlers are called, you may simply forget to wire them.

Comment: Jimi yes I added them manually. I initialized them double clicking the designed buttons and such and then I changed it after some time when I was trying to figure out what was wrong. For the second thing I am not sure. How do I check? I was led to believe that double clicking a button which brings up "button1_Click" executes the even once a button is clicked...

Comment: apomene Hmm it seems not! I have tried this code to test out the first button : 

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Test", "Test",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

But didn't get a message box. Do you have any idea as to why the button click is not being registered?

Comment: Add a new Button to the Form designer. Double click it: the code file is opened and the handler is created, the event subscription is also added to the form.designer.cs file. Now, add `MessageBox.Show("Clicked");` in the new handler. Run the Project. Click the new Button.

Comment: Jimi I have tried to recreate a test button and the event executed as expected. It seems like that I've got some junk in Form1.Designed.cs that got there during the troubleshooting and it messes up the events. I will have to recreate the buttons manually now and copy the code and try it out for the rest but this now worked with the first part that haven't even worked before so I think it should work just fine after I try it out. Thank you for your help!

Comment: To "re-wire" a button to an EXISTING handler...Select the Button.  In the Properties Pane, click on the Lightning Bolt Icon to see the EVENTS.  Scroll down to the "Click" entry.  To the right of that, click the drop down arrow and select the EXISTING method that you want to be run when the button is clicked.